# How should I order my ctor parameters for DI/IOC?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm a bit of a DI newbie, so forgive me if this is the wrong approach or a silly question.

Let's say I have a form which creates/updates an order, and I know it's going to need to retrieve a list of products and customers to display. I want to pass in the Order object that it's editing, but I also want to inject the ProductsService and CustomersService as dependencies.

So I will want my IoC container (whichever one I go with) to supply the services, but it'll be up to the calling code to supply the Order object to edit.

Should I declare the constructor as taking the Order object as the first parameter and the ProductsService and CustomersService after that, eg:

```
public OrderForm(Order order, ProductsService prodsSvc, CustomersService custsSvc)
```

... or should the dependencies come first and the Order object last, eg:

```
public OrderForm(ProductsService prodsSvc, CustomersService custsSvc, Order order)
```

Does it matter? Does it depend on which IoC container I use? Or is there a "better" way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with @aku's answer.

I think what you're doing is fine and there are also other ways to do it that are no more or less right.  For instance, one may question whether this object should be depending on services in the first place.

Regardless of DI, I feel it is helpful to clarify in your mind at least the kind of state each object holds, such as the real state (Order), derived state (if any), and dependencies (services):

http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/09/18/spelunking/

On any constructor or method, I prefer the real data to be passed first and dependencies or external stuff to be passed last.  So in your example I'd prefer the first.

Answer (score 5):

Matt, you shouldn't mix normal parameters with dependencies. Since your object will be created in the internals of IoC container, how are you going to specify necessary arguments?

Mixing dependency and normal arguments will make logic of your program more complicated.

In this case it would be better to declare dependency properties (i.e. remove dependencies from constructor) or initialize **order** field after IoC constructed **OrderForm** and resolved it's dependencies (i.e. remove normal parameters from constructor).

Also you can declare all of your parameters, including **order** as dependencies.

Comment: Ok, this is making sense. So either I use property injection for all my dependencies, or ONLY pass dependencies into the ctor and introduce a property for the "necessary" object?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Don't mix DP and normal properties because it can lead to unpredicted problems and limit the range of suitable IoC frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

I feel a bit uneasy about allowing an instance of OrderForm to be instantiated without the required reference to an Order instance.  One reason might be that this would prevent me from doing upfront checking for null orders.  Any further thoughts?

I suppose I could take some comfort in knowing that OrderForm objects will only be instantiated by a Factory method that ensures the Order property is set after making the call to the IoC framework.

Comment: In my answer I proposed several approaches including one with mandatory **order** parameter. Questions however was about mixing DP and normal properties. My answer is - don't mix. I would be happy to hear constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0):

I am just a bit late to the party, but I would suggest using a factory in this case: the factory constructor would take the required `*Service` dependencies which the DI system would resolve and inject, while its `Build()` method would accept any additional state parameter - like `Order`. The factory would be, of course, registered itself in the DI system and would play just nicely with it.

```csharp
public class OrderFormFactory
{
  private readonly ProductsService _prodsSvc;
  private readonly CustomersService _custsSvc;

  public OrderFormFactory(ProductsService prodsSvc, CustomersService custsSvc)
  {
    _prodsService = prodsService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(prodsService));
    _custsSvc = custsSvc ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(custsSvc));
  }

  public OrderForm Build(Order order)
  {
    // TODO: Any additional logic

    return new OrderForm(_prodsService, _custsSvc, order);
  }
}
```